# jQuery Unslide - Touch doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, responsive-design, slideshow

I already solved this, and I'm only posting to help others save some time.

I am using unslider for a business website, a website I'm making responsive, so the feature of adding touch support to the slider is appealing. Unfortunately it doesn't work straight out of the box, as the author claims.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**UPDATE**
The unslider plugin I used, was outdated. I downloaded it from unslider.com where I first found it( it's still an outdated version there), hence I had the difficulties.

If you need to get the latest version, go to: https://github.com/idiot/unslider/

And if you want to see my issue report: https://github.com/idiot/unslider/issues/69

---

The problem is that the author hasn't updated his project in 4 months, and since then the swipe event has been moved from $.event.swipe to $.event.special.swipe.

The problem occurs in line 108 of the unslider plugin, where it test for the existence of the swipe plugin.

```
108: if($.event.swipe) {
109:    this.el.on('swipeleft', _.prev).on('swiperight', _.next);
```

Just change it to:

```
108: if($.event.special.swipe) {
109:    this.el.on('swipeleft', _.prev).on('swiperight', _.next);
```

It's an easy fix, but will take some googling to figure out.

If you want to be sure it will work with earlier versions, you can do this:

```
108: if($.event.special.swipe || $.event.special.swipe) {
109:    this.el.on('swipeleft', _.prev).on('swiperight', _.next);
```

But I don't recommend that.

**Also,** the author doesn't mention this, but the swipe plugin page does, you need to include jquery.event.move in addition to jquery.event.swipe in your scripts.

I hope this helped someone :)

---

To answer the comment below:

Remember to include all files, in the right order, and remember all of them:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.event.move.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.event.swipe.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/unslider.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  I checked my script and when I downloaded it it already had this:   if ($.event.special['swipe'] || $.Event('swipe')) {
    el.on('swipeleft swiperight swipeLeft swipeRight', function(e) {
     e.type.toLowerCase() == 'swipeleft' ? _.next() : _.prev();
    });
   };    But it still doesn't work.  I also included jquery.event.swipe.js but it won't work.  any ideas?

Comment: Did you include the script files, in the right order?
Also, are you sure it doesn't work, its not as intuitive in its feel, as you might think.

Comment: i am trying to swipe it the way i would swipe to see images... the dots in the bottom are there and clickable but the swiping doesn't work..

Comment: with regards to the order of the scripts, i first have jquery, unsnlider, and then the swipe event file.

Comment: I just updated my answer above, I think you are missing `/scripts/jquery.event.move.js`.

Comment: Thanks Andre.  But in the files i downloaded i only have this file:  jquery.event.swipe.js

Comment: Yup, I made the same mistake. You need to download a library that swipe depends on:
http://stephband.info/jquery.event.swipe/

Look under projects, and click the link, where its says Dependency:
Or just go here: http://github.com/stephband/jquery.event.move

Comment: I do have one more question.  I have 4 slides and after the 4th slides ends the slider goes back in reverse order.  how can i change it so that after the last slide ends it goes back to the first one by going next rather than going past the previous slides?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33579/discussion-between-starbucks-and-andre-snede-hansen)

Comment: lord, i cant make this work... i dont have images, i have divs with divs and tweets inside those last divs. Everything is inside a ul with their respective li items...

Comment: http://dev.warnermusic.com.mx i have use this two plugins for the twitter slider inside each "artista" profile... with no luck, the thing is that i have an UNORDER LIST instead of just images... so in this case how should i do for this plugin to work??

Comment: @AndréSnedeHansen how can i add jquery effects to the slide when a slide is shown?

Comment: @starbucks I think you should use the `complete` event in the setup of unslider. Either that way you can get the div that is active, or you will have to select it, I would think.

Comment: @AndréSnedeHansen Thanks.  I made complete set to true but after that nothing changed.  Do I have to hard code something in? I am new to JS and JQuery to a bit unclear as to what I would have to do.  Thanks again!

Comment: I think you need to start a new question here on stackoverflow, to get a proper answer to your questions

Comment: As of May 2014 the plugin has been updated in github--with working touch transitions. The site has not been updated however, so this answer was very helpful!

Comment: @im3r3k You are welcome. Seems to be a common problem with the unslide project.

Comment: Two years after this initial answer is given, it is still relevant and perfect. Thanks @AndréSnedeHansen!

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me, but after extensive tweaks I got it to work smoothly. I blogged step by step what I did, but not why.
http://frazer.livejournal.com/21898.html

I hope that helps, especially people new to drupal.

In short - I added this to my page and I got responsive movement:

```
var wrap = jQuery(".slides_wrap"),
   slides = wrap.find(".img_slide"),
   width = slides.width();
slides
.on("move", function(e) {
          // Move slides with the finger
// banner has moved -100% when one slide to the right
   var left = 100 * e.deltaX / width;
   wrap[0].style.left = parseInt(wrap[0].style.left.replace("%", ""))+left+"%";
})
.on("moveend", function(e) {
setTimeout(function(){
   var left = parseFloat(wrap[0].style.left.replace("%", ""));
   var left_rounded = Math.round(left/100)*100;
   if(left%100!=0){
     jQuery(".slides_wrap").animate({"left":left_rounded + "%"});
  }
},800);
});
```

Comment: Please post the answer content here, in case the link goes down.

Comment: Actually, fixing the unslider.js like this did add swiping, but it didn't look responsive, only a complete swipe would make it move.

Answer (score 0):

As of today (November 2014) it seems the swipe functionality was replaced by move. The plugin's url is http://stephband.info/jquery.event.move/ . Just import this one instead of swipe.

I hope someone find this useful. Had to check the commits to found out.

Comment: Swipe and movie is both made by Stephband, and Move is already included, as Swipe depends on it.

Comment: Nevertheless touch didn't worked for me until I changed swipe for move. Strange, right?

Answer (score -1):

I am bumping on this subject as I am a real noob and had trouble to install the Jquery.event.swipe.js module
It's now solved, but here a few things noobs like me would make sure to check :

- make sure you have both github.com/stephband/jquery.event.move.js and github.com/stephband/jquery.event.swipe.js in your projet folder
- make a reference to those 2 files in your html file
- make sure you have the unslider.js file in your projet folder as well (I had the unslider.min.js file instead which wasn't complete enough to make the swipe plugins work)

No extra javascript code is necessary in the html file, it should work with the above (at least it did for me)

both very good free tools, thanks to the coders