# Unslider not loading on webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, unslider

So Im using the really nifty unslider which I love but for some reason it's just refusing to work on my site. I am a student learning basic html so forgive me if the mistake is really minor and silly.

Im using the lastest Jquery as well as the provided Javascript from Unslider.

my codes:

```css
* {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
body{
 background: url(../images/subtle_white_mini_waves.png) repeat;
}
#wrapper{
 width:1180px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.button{
 background:url(../images/navbarbutton.png);
 width:175px;
 margin-top:66px;
}
.button a{
 padding:35px 20px;
}
.navside{
 width:170px;
 height:89px;
 margin-top:66px;
}
.nav ul {
    *zoom:1;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.nav ul:before,.nav ul:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.nav ul:after {
    clear:both;
}
.nav ul > li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
.nav ul li a {
 font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size:16px;
    display:block;
    line-height:1.2em;
    color:#fff;
 text-align:center;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.nav ul li ul li a{
 font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;
    display:block;
    line-height:1.2em;
    color:#fff;
 text-align:center;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.button a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#033782;
 height:20px;
}
.nav ul li.button{
 width:175px;
 height: 89px;
}
.nav ul li.sub1{
 width:175px;
 height: 50px;
}
.nav ul li.sub2{
 width:175px;
 height: 70px;
}
.nav ul li.sub1 a{
 padding: 15px 20px;
}
.nav ul li.sub1 a:hover{
 color:#666;
}
.nav ul li.sub2 a{
 padding: 15px 20px;
}
.nav ul li.sub2 a:hover{
 color:#666;
}
.nav li ul {
    background:#7bb0e2;
 position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:89px;
    z-index:1;
}
.nav ul > li:hover ul {
    left:0;
}
.nav li ul li {
    overflow:hidden;
    max-height:0;
    -webkit-transition:max-height 1000ms ease;
    -moz-transition:max-height 1000ms ease;
    -o-transition:max-height 1000ms ease;
 -ms-transition: max-heightheight 1000ms ease;
    transition:max-height 1000ms ease;
}
.nav li ul a {
    border:none;
}
.nav li ul a:hover {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
.nav ul > li:hover ul li {
    max-height:150px;
}

.banner { 
 position: relative;
 overflow: auto;
 width:100%;
 top:-74px;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 z-index:-10;
}
.banner ul{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}
.bammer li{
 list-style:none;
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
}
.banner ul li {
 float: left;
 display:block;
 min-height:370px;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
 -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
 -o-background-size: 100% auto;
 -ms-background-size: 100% auto;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 background-position-y:-75px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Beyond - Home</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="scripts/unslider.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.banner').unslider();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
 <nav class="nav">
     <ul>
         <li>
             <div class="navside">
                <img src="images/navbarleft.png" width="170" height="89">
                </div>
            </li>
         <li class="button">
             <a href="#">Programes</a>
                 <ul>
                     <li class="sub2"><a href="#">Problem<br>De-escalation</a></li>
                        <li class="sub2"><a href="#">Family Strenghthening</a></li>
                        <li class="sub2"><a href="#">Community Integration</a></li>
                        <li class="sub2"><a href="#">Support Programmes</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
         <li class="button">
             <a href="#">How you can help</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="sub1"><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
                    <li class="sub1"><a href="#">Volunteer</a></li>
                    <li class="sub1"><a href="#">Sponsor</a></li>
                    <li class="sub1"><a href="#">Partner</a></li>
                    <li class="sub1"><a href="#">Join the Staff</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
             <div id="logo">
                 <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" width="140" height="225" alt="Beyond - Logo"></a>
                </div>
            </li>
         <li class="button">
             <a href="#">About Us</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="sub1"><a href="#">Our Board</a></li>
                    <li class="sub1"><a href="#">News and Views</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
         <li class="button">
             <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="sub1"><a href="#">Facilities</a></li>
                    <li class="sub1"><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
             <div class="navside">
                <img src="images/navbarright.png" width="170" height="89">
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    
    <div id="slider">
     <div class="banner">
            <ul>
                <li style="background-image:url('http://lokacion.com/electra/wp-content/uploads/sites/52/2014/01/electra_slider-1-1180x370.jpg');"></li>
                <li style="background-image: url('http://lokacion.com/electra/wp-content/uploads/sites/52/2014/01/electra_slider-1-1180x370.jpg');"></li>
                <li style="background-image: url('http://lokacion.com/electra/wp-content/uploads/sites/52/2014/01/electra_slider-1-1180x370.jpg');"></li>
            </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="content">
     <div id="video">
        </div>
        <div id="userobj">
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can u create a fiddle?

Comment: you used .bammer li{ istead of .banner li in your css

Comment: Im not sure how to go about using fiddle but here http://jsfiddle.net/csktgav3/ the images aren't in but the navigation bar is exactly how I want it

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Unslide - Touch doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545319/jquery-unslide-touch-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the date on this, you may have sorted it already - but for those who find the question in the future, there's all the information you need in another post on this site:

[jQuery Unslide - Touch doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17545319/4819822)

Used it myself today, and Unslider working well.

Hope it helps!  :0)

HR